# Unit test model bound controller action with unbound fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sorry if that description isn't clear...wasn't sure how else to put it.

I have a custom membership registration form that I've created. It posts to a controller action in which I use model binding to populate a "User" object. The form has a "Password" field and a "ConfirmPassword" field. The Password field binds to the User object when binding occurs, but the ConfirmPassword doesn't. So, in my controller action, when I validate that Password and ConfirmPasswords match, I check to ensure that user.Password and Request.Form["ConfirmPassword"] are equal. Everything is working fine, until I get to the unit test.

I'm able to pass a User object into the controller action as a parameter for testing...but Request.Form["ConfirmPassword"] doesn't exist in the test context. How can I provide a Request.Form object to the test to use for testing purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search for the answer, and came up with this link - it purports to have solutions for both Moq and Rhino Mocks. They're using ASP.NET MVC, so it may not be pertinent to your solution, but I'll pass it on.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1309792.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much. I feel kinda silly now. Not sure why I didn't think of that for myself. Just mock the Form collection on the Request context. That was the nudge in the right direction that I needed. Thanks again.